# Why aren't my table columns centered in the correct way?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have the following code:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{.\label{}}
    \begin{center}

            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X X X X X X}
            \toprule
            \textbf{$T_{0}$} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Combination therapy}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Chemotherapy}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Immunotherapy}} \\
            \midrule
            &CIS&HIS&CIS&HIS&CIS&HIS\\
            \midrule
            $4.0\times 10^7$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{X}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{X}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{X}}\\
            $3.5\times 10^7$ & \quad\textbf{X} & \textbf{$\surd$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{X}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{X}}\\
            $2.5\times 10^7$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{$\surd$}} & \textbf{X} & \textbf{$\surd$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{X}}\\
            $3.2\times 10^6$ &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{$\surd$}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{$\surd$}} &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{X}}\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

However the columns are not with the right width as you can see in the printscreen:

[image]

What I am doing wrong? Even when I do this, the result is the same:

```
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c}
        \toprule
        \textbf{$T_{0}$} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Combination therapy}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Chemotherapy}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Immunotherapy}} \\
        \midrule
        &CIS&HIS&CIS&HIS&CIS&HIS\\
        \midrule
        $4.0\times 10^7$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{X}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{X}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{X}}\\
        $3.5\times 10^7$ & \quad\textbf{X} & \textbf{$\surd$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{X}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{X}}\\
        $2.5\times 10^7$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{$\surd$}} & \textbf{X} & \textbf{$\surd$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{X}}\\
        $3.2\times 10^6$ &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{$\surd$}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{$\surd$}} &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{X}}\\
        \bottomrule
 \end{tabularx}
```

[image]

Comment: `X` is not meant for centering

Comment: Make sure that when you insert an image in a question, the block of code is *not* selected. Note the `[` at the start of the first code block, the `][1]` at the end, and that all the `[` and `]` in the code has been replaced by `\[` and `\]`.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions and observations:

- Instead of `$\surd$`, you may want to use `\checkmark`.
- Set up a centered version of the `X` column type if the contents of the `X` column should be centered rather than fully justified.
- Do allow a linebreak in the expression "Combination therapy".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,amssymb}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{.\label{}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} c *{6}{C} @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{$T_{0}$} 
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize\hspace{0pt}}C}{\textbf{Combination therapy}} % allow linebreak
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Chemotherapy}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textbf{Immunotherapy}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7} 
&CIS&HIS&CIS&HIS&CIS&HIS\\
\midrule
$4.0\times 10^7$ & \mc{\textbf{X}} & \mc{\textbf{X}} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textbf{X}}\\
$3.5\times 10^7$ & \textbf{X} & \checkmark & \mc{\textbf{X}} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textbf{X}}\\
$2.5\times 10^7$ & \mc{\checkmark} & \textbf{X} & \checkmark & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textbf{X}}\\
$3.2\times 10^6$ & \mc{\checkmark} & \mc{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textbf{X}}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the second column head, which is too wide. It's easy to break it in two lines with `makecell`. I also replaced our checkmark and crosses with true glyphs from `pifont` and used `siunitx` to simplify typing numbers in scientific notation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, makecell, caption}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\boldmath\bfseries}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{.\label{}}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{S[table-format =1.1e1]*{6}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}X} }
    \Xhline{1pt}
    {\thead{$T_{0}$}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Combination \\ therapy}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Chemotherapy}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Immunotherapy}} \\
    \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{\belowrulesep}
                      & CIS & HIS & CIS & HIS & CIS & HIS \\
    \midrule
    4.0e7 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ding{56}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ding{56}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ding{56}} \\
    \addlinespace
    3.5e7 & \bfseries\ding{56} & \ding{52} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ding{56}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ding{56}} \\
    \addlinespace
    2.5e7 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ding{52}} & \ding{56} & \ding{52} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ding{56}} \\
    \addlinespace
    3.2e6 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ding{52}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ding{52}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ding{56}} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note you shouldn't use the `center` environment within `figure` or `table`, as this adds unwanted vertical spacing. Use `\centering` instead.
[image]